# Spree Engine/API Mounting Routes

Tags: spree

I am mounting spree at a "custom" location, like so:

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/shop'
```

This works fine for the main portion of the site, but API calls in the admin side get 404ed.

```
No route matches [GET] "/shop/api/orders/R373466857/shipments/H36171240358/ship.json"
```

I noticed that the API routes look like this:

```
ready_api_order_shipment_path    PUT     /api/orders/:order_id/shipments/:id/ready(.:format)     spree/api/shipments#ready {:format=>"json"}
ship_api_order_shipment_path     PUT     /api/orders/:order_id/shipments/:id/ship(.:format)  spree/api/shipments#ship {:format=>"json"}
add_api_order_shipment_path  PUT     /api/orders/:order_id/shipments/:id/add(.:format)   spree/api/shipments#add {:format=>"json"}
remove_api_order_shipment_path   PUT     /api/orders/:order_id/shipments/:id/remove(.:format)    spree/api/shipments#remove {:format=>"json"}
```

Notice the lack of `/shop` prepending the relevant routes.  Any ideas?  I can just redirect them in my HTTP server, but that seems like a godawful hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your engine is being mounted correctly.  In your rake routes you should see something like this:

```
1| Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
2| spree  /shop Spree::Core::Engine
3|
4| Routes for Spree::Core::Engine:
5|     new_spree_user_session GET    /user/spree_user/sign_in(.:format)   spree/user_sessions#new
```

All of the spree routes are mounted under /shop as shown by line 2 above.  The Routes for Spree::Core::Engine section lists the routes relative to the path the engine is mounted under.  It's a bit confusing, but that's the way rake routes works.

I believe that you're having problems because you're trying to do a **GET** request to a route which only accepts **PUT** requests.  If you switch your HTTP request type, you should  get things to resolve correctly.

Comment: You are absolutely correct - I was misinterpreting a 401 on the PUT for a 404 on the GET (which is what I got when I tried to visit that route manually in the browser, and then got a 404).  It turns out there's some kind of authorization problem that is the actual problem...  back to the drawing board.